# loading MIMIC III into SQL Server

Tags: mimic-iii

I'd like to load the MIMIC III data into SQL Server because that's what I know best. The problem with the csv files is that some fields contain commas as part of the data. It would be far easier to work with a unique delimiter instead of trying to implement workarounds for comma data inside csv files. I've searched all of the MIMIC III csv files and the following characters are never used:

Ⅎ ❶ ① ↘

If the data could be extracted into flat files using a delimiter that never appears in the data, it would make it trivial to load the data into SQL Server. Using an alternate, well chosen delimiter character is a far more robust solution to the problem than continually implementing workarounds for csv files.

Comment: Since it looks like an issue with MIMIC, and not a question about it, maybe you can raise an issue on https://github.com/MIT-LCP/mimic-code/issues ?

Answer (score 3):

The data files conform to the [RFC 4180 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), which is as close as CSVs get to a formal standard.

[image: RFC 4180 specification]

Loading a RFC 4180 formatted CSV is trivial for many database systems. For example, the load command in Postgres is:

`\copy ADMISSIONS FROM 'ADMISSIONS.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER`

Using a different delimiter is an option, but there would need to be a compelling reason to do so. Commas within text fields are handled by the standard CSV (RFC 4180) format.